# Parse timestamp and Hex file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parsing, binary, hex

I have a txt file that contains a timestamp, hex data, and encoded code.
I need to parse just the hex data and insert it in a file.
Here it is a n example of the file:

```
15:25:21  0000  04 24 E8 03 04 00 B0 04 00 00 5B AA 44 04 24 E8  .$è...°...[ªD.$è
      0010  03 04 00 B0 04 00 00 5B AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00  ...°...[ªD.$è...
      0020  B0 04 00 00 5B AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B0 04 00  °...[ªD.$è...°..
      0030  00 5B AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA  .[ªD.$è...±...Zª
      0040  44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA 44 04 24  D.$è...±...ZªD.$
      0050  E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04  è...±...ZªD.$è..
      0060  00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04  .±...ZªD.$è...±.
      0070  00 00 5A AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A  ..ZªD.$è...±...Z
      0080  AA 44 04 24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA 44 04  ªD.$è...±...ZªD.
      0090  24 E8 03 04 00 B1 04 00 00 5A AA 44 04 24 E8 03  $è...±...ZªD.$è.
```

I have a problem parsing it, I was able to parse (orders) as columns getting the timestamp cell, hex cells (for each value) and encoded cell, but getting stuck to get the full hex values.
I need to extract just the 04... 03.. etc etc.
Any help?

Comment: I did this, but then i am not able to separete hex by all the rest 
fp = fopen("data.txt", 'rt');
C1 = textscan(fp, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');

Comment: You should be able to simply read line by line, `strplit()` on the whitespace and throw away entries `18:end`

Comment: you mean: T=strsplit(data,'');?

Comment: @Adriaan 18:end is not fine, I need just the hex (2 chars) not the encoded